# Percona and MySQL audit

Tags: mysql, percona

I am trying to audit MySQL commands for users on Percona. 
Current version of Percona is 55-5.5.22-rel25.2.237.rhel5.

The following URL gives guidance, however I do not know how to get it working.

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/diagnostics/mysql_syslog.html

I attempted to add to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
syslog
```

However I keep getting error messages starting.

```
130601 18:50:09 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--syslog'
```

Anyone managed to get audit commands using that option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syslog option goes in the `[mysql]` section, not in the `[mysqld]` section, it's only for the client, not the server.

So this does *not* provide any auditing of mysql commands, for that you need to enable query logging. For MySQL you'll find documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html), I didn't find percona-specific documentation unfortunately.

Comment: -1 : Sorry, `syslog` is not for `[mysqld]` or `[mysql]`

Comment: Read the link he posted. It may be percona specific, but it's definitely going in the [mysql] section.

Comment: I stand corrected. Please edit your answer (change format, anything) so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: Done. Didn't know you can't remove a downvote without edit (not a heavy voter), that seems odd.

Comment: Removed my downvote and upvoted you. Thanks for the reminder to keep current and thoroughly read the question.